# Placing value on stack using alloca function or static keyword

Tags: c, memory-management, stack-memory

I have an abstract "x vs y" question. In C programming language if I have some small amount of data which I want to store somewhere in RAM, I suppose typical options are the next ones:

- to define a variable, which is going to be located in the "slow" heap unless some compiler optimisation;
- to `malloc()` some space in the "slow" heap and to write here something;
- to define a static variable, `static` keyword means related to stack, which means "fast" to me;
- to allocate value in the "fast" stack using `alloca()` .

So what is the difference between `static` keyword and `alloca()` non-standard function?

Comment: Besides the fact that these assumptions are all wrong, have you decide on the lifetime of the object? Do you want it to last for the entirety of the program? Or the duration of a function call? Or until you manually `free` it?

Comment: Only the last question makes *some* sense. `alloca` is allocating the space on the local stack, and will be gone after the current stack frame becomes invalid (function returns). `static` variables are allocated in the global data section and persist over the whole program run time. FWIW, the usecases for `alloca`  are pretty limited, and personally I never used it explicitly (however it might be used implicitly by the compiler for VLAs and such).

Comment: Said that, you do not typically decide on the storage class base on this "slow/fast" distinction, but based on the required lifetime of the data, it's required visibility/scope and sometimes it's size.

Comment: @Eimrine, Concerning fast versus slow: [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Answer (score 3):

First things first, your assumptions/understanding about the types of these variables are not accurate. Let's go through them one by one.

1. By defining a variable, I assume you mean declaring it like `int x;`. The behavior of this depends on where such a declaration appears.

   i. If it is inside a function, it is what we call a local/auto
   variable. This would most likely be allocated on the stack (if it is
   not optimized away by the compiler).

   ii. If it appears at the file scope, it would be a global variable which would most likely be allocated in the global memory.

   Neither of these allocations are "slow" (if you compare it to the heap allocation costs)
2. Calling `malloc`. This always allocates memory on the heap and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. Depending on how you define it, this could be slow since calling `malloc` executes code which figures out the space allocated on the heap. Memory allocated such a way must be free'd by calling `free` on the same pointer.
3. Using the `static` keyword. `static` has nothing to do with the stack. When `static` appears inside a function, it is similar to making the variable global and will reside in the global memory. Using `static` at the file scope also makes the variable, but it is accessible only from the same file (as opposed to globals, which can accessed from other files as long as they have a declaration).
4. Using `alloca`. Calling `alloca` is similar to calling `malloc` in the API but allocates space for you on the stack. This memory is never supposed to be manually `free`'d.

What you are missing is the other half of your question that determines what is the appropriate choice for you and that is the expected lifetimes of these objects.

Lifetime refers to how long the variables lives and would be valid to access. Let's go over the same 4 options and look at their lifetimes -

1. The lifetime of a variable defined like `int x;` depends again on if it is local or global. If it is defined to be global, the lifetime is the entirety of the program and can be used any time. If defined locally in a function, the lifetime is till the end of the scope it is defined in (either the function call or within a block of {}). Be carefully taking addresses of such variables and not to access them after the scope they are defined in ends. (as suggested by @JonathanLeffler in comments)
2. Memory allocated using `malloc` is accessible until you call `free` on the corresponding pointer. Which means the lifetime here is "dynamic".
3. Variables with the `static` keyword have the same lifetime as globals in 1.
4. Memory allocated using `alloca` has the same lifetime as variables defined locally like in 1. Once again be careful with the pointers and not to use them after the function returns.

Given all these choices and their tradeoffs, try to answer the two questions - 1. What is the expected lifetime and 2. Where do you want the variable to reside a.k.a., do you want to pay the cost of calling `malloc` and `free` and you will have your answer.

Comment: Note that MS Visual C's implementation of [`alloca()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170) is deprecated in favour of their `_malloca()` which uses the heap or stack as appropriate and must always be paired with a call to `_freea()`.

Comment: I would use the correct working "`static storage duration`", "`automatic storage duration`", "`allocated storage duration`" & "`thread storage duration`"

Comment: Re “it is accessible only from the same file”: All objects are accessible (can be read or written) from anywhere in a program. Pointers can be used for this. `static` limits scope and linkage, not accessibility: The name of an object, its identifier, is not known (usable to reference the object) outside its scope, and `static` limits its linkage to internal linkage.